# Szemerédi's regularity lemma for binary operations

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Szemerédi's regularity lemma is an approximate structure theorem for
all large graphs (symmetric binary relations). There are versions for
multicolored graphs and directed graphs. Is there an analogous
result for binary operations? In other words, what can we say about
the structure of a binary operation on a large (finite) set?

Comment: You can send any binary operation $f\colon X\times X \to X$ to $\sigma \circ f$ for any permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_X$, which kind of suggests that the $X$ codomain is just a set of colors. In other words, you maybe might as well look at edge-colored directed graphs (where the number of colors grows with the number of vertices).

Comment: The graph of a binary operation $f:X \times X \to X$ is too sparse of a hypergraph for standard hypergraph regularity theorems to apply.  But it can be useful to apply the regularity lemma to denser hypergraphs associated to $f$, such as $\{ (f(x,y), f(x,y'), f(x',y), f(x',y')): x,y,x',y' \} \subset X^4$, which I used for instance in https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2894 to understand the expansion properties of $f$.

Comment: @Sam: that doesn't seem like the right permutation action to me; surely you want to consider $\sigma$ acting on all three copies of $X$ simultaneously? In other words, considering magma structures on $X$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: my point was to suggest that, from the perspective of these Szemerédi-type structural results, $X$ being the codomain has little to do with $X\times X$ being the domain. You could take as codomain any set with the same cardinality as $X$. Unless you're iteratively applying the multiplication or something...